# Changing div background-image to specific image with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, background-image

I pretty much don't know jquery at all. Knowing HTML, PHP and CSS I can understand it a bit and alter already existing scripts but now I have hitted an brick wall.

I'm trying to create image gallery where you can click an image and it shows fullscreen as background. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the background to change.

What I tried was to change the background image of "background" by clicking "changer". The image that was supposed to be the new background is DSC_2363 which I put in the function.

**EDIT:** You can see the page in progress at http://lautamaki.net/omasivu2/

My CSS is like this:

```
      .background{
        background-image: url(images/DSC_1418.JPG);
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
      }
```

Jquery:

```
    $('.changer').click(function(image){
      $('.background').css("background-image", "url(images/".image.".JPG)");
    });
```

And finally HTML:

```
<div class="background">
</div>
<div class="content">
  <img class="changer" src="images/DSC_2363.JPG" width="30" onClick="function(DSC_2363)">
</div>
```

I know there are already questions like these but none of those helped me at all. Hopefully someone gets what I'm trying and can help me, thanks!

**EDIT:** Changed

```
 $('.background').css("background-image", "url(images/".image.".JPG)");
```

to

```
 $('.background').css("background-image", "url(images/"+image+".JPG)");
```

but still not working.

Comment: check updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373410/#22373429)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `+` instead of `.` to concatenate string in `Javascript`

```
$('.changer').click(function(image){
    $('.background').css("background-image", "url(images/" + image + ".JPG)");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript  we use `+` for concatenation  not `.`

```
$('.changer').click(function (image) {
    $('.background').css("background-image", "url(images/" + image + ".JPG)");
    //                                                     ^       ^
});
```

---

Updated code after OP Updated Question

Change your html add `data-image = "DSC_2363"` instead of onclick function

```
<div class="content">
  <img class="changer" data-image = "DSC_2363" src="images/DSC_2363.JPG" width="30" >
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.changer').click(function () {
    var image = $(this).data('image'); //get data-image attribute
    $('.background').css("background-image", "url(images/" + image + ".JPG)");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
 $('.changer').on('click',function(image){
      $('.background').css("background-image", "url(images/"+image+".JPG)");
    });
```